# Does the include? method work with an array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Say I have some object array:

```
employees:[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

Can I use Ruby's include? method to do something like this:

```
employees.include?("'firstName' = 'John'")
```

Comment: What is your question? "Can I use ruby methods in javascript", is that it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: JSON != JavaScript. But the question really is very unclear (not least because the quoted JSON isn't valid JSON, in two different ways). Bailey - Maybe you can clarify, and post valid JSON?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "JSON != JavaScript" - I think I have a clue about this. :) But there's no such thing as json array in ruby. It's either a string or a ruby array.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Yeah, I figured it was a string containing JSON, or a Ruby array resulting from deserializing JSON. But as this is apparently yet another ask-and-run... **sigh** :-)

Comment: @Bailey, please clarify what you're exactly asking? is employees object a string in JSON format? or an Array of Hashes(probably parsed JSON string)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev *"There's no such thing as JSON array in Ruby"*: Not sure if that statement is perfectly correct but the OP is referring to the array in JSON: `[]`. If you still doubt it, see [JSON Schema primitive types](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor8).

Comment: @konsolebox: obviously, I wasn't clear enough. JSON has arrays. Ruby has arrays. But you can't have a json array in ruby (if you could, how would you distinguish it from ruby array?)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You don't really distinguish it. JSON arrays are stored in Ruby as Ruby arrays.

Comment: Perhaps I was assumptive that the OP already parsed the JSON string. But it's pretty obvious how you get JSON data out from a string. And the best way to present JSON is not by a presentable structure of Ruby arrays but a JSON string instead.

Comment: And so I upvoted for it to be re-opened. It appears my obvious assumption was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#any?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) instead:

```
employees.any?{ |e| e["firstName"] == "John" }
```

- `Enumerable` is an included module of `Array` so that should work with arrays as well.
- This assumes JSON code has been parsed from raw JSON string to Ruby arrays and hashes.

Comment: You may want to mention that you are assuming he has already parsed a JSON string into a Ruby hash.

Comment: @MarkThomas That may not be necessary for the OP.

Comment: Answers on SO should be written to benefit all, not just the OP. But this question is closed, so it's a moot point.

Comment: @MarkThomas I'm actually interested to see any terms or document that says like that as I've encountered a lot of people saying it. Anything like because it's what the community do is not valid to me.

Comment: Benefitting future readers is definitely the ethos of SO; given your rep I'm surprised you are doubtful. There are examples everywhere, such as the close option that reads (in part): "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers" and countless discussions on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Hi, thanks. Sorry to post and run. This is exactly what I was looking for.